# Angular 2 Extract JSON based on selected form value

Tags: json, typescript, angular

I am trying to extract a specific JSON values based on a user selected input that is the key and turn it into [`QuestionBase<any>[]`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html). Currently, I am doing this which works for only extracting `test`:

```
// dropdown HTML
<select class="form-control" name="test" id="test" (ngModel)="test" (change)="onSelectChange($event, test.form)">
       <option selected disabled hidden style='display: none' value=''></option>
       <option value="test">Test</option>
       <option value="other">Other</option>
</select>

// question-list.component.ts
onSelectChange($event: any, form: NgForm) {
    this.getQuestions();
}
getQuestions() {
    this.questionService.getQuestions()
        .subscribe(questions => this.questions = questions.sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order),
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
}

// question.service.ts
getQuestions(): Observable<QuestionBase<any>[]> {
return this.http.get(this.jsonUrl)
  .map(this.extractTest)
  .catch(this.handleError);
}
private extractTest(res: Response) {
 let body = res.json();
 return body["test"] || {};
}

// JSON
{
    "test": [{
               key: 'firstName',
               label: 'First name',
               value: 'Bombasto',
               required: true,
               order: 1
            }, {
              key: 'brave',
              label: 'Bravery Rating',
              options: [
               {key: 'solid',  value: 'Solid'},
               {key: 'great',  value: 'Great'},
               {key: 'good',   value: 'Good'},
               {key: 'unproven', value: 'Unproven'}
               ],
              order: 2
            }],
    "other": [{
            key: 'emailAddress',
            label: 'Email',
            type: 'email',
           order: 1
        }]   
}
```

So far, I have tried passing the selected value as an argument to `getQuestions()` and `extractTest` so that I could return `body[selected] || {}` in `extractTest`, but when I do so, I get an undefined object in my subscribe function and the sort throws an error. I think I might be misunderstanding how map or subscribe works.

Does anybody have any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably your have to send parameter like this :-

```
// question.service.ts
getQuestions(): Observable<QuestionBase<any>[]> {
return this.http.get(this.jsonUrl)
  .map(res => this.extractTest(res))  //here you have to send parameter and return it back to the subscribe function
  .catch(this.handleError);
}
private extractTest(res: Response) {
 let body = res.json();
 return body["test"] || {};
}
```

if not solved your problem do comment here.

## Update

According to me if you are using `.map` with multiline then you have to use `return` keyword for return it back something but when you are using simple single line `.map` than no need to write `return`. thts the main difference according to me. so in your case try this

```
return this.http.get(this.jsonUrl).map(res => { return this.extractTest(res, selected); }) .catch(this.handleError);
```

instead of this

```
return this.http.get(this.jsonUrl).map(res => { this.extractTest(res, selected); }) .catch(this.handleError);
```

Comment: I had tried the map function with brackets for multi-line code such as `return this.http.get(this.jsonUrl).map(res => { 
  this.extractTest(res, selected); })  
  .catch(this.handleError);` , but I didn't try it with one line. I don't understand why there was a difference, but thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh, I see now. Thanks so much!